# Error when trying to run a repeated measure ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

Here is my code:

```
res.aov <- anova_test(
  data = tomato1, 
  dv = Pb, 
  wid = Plant.Id,
  within = Year, 
  between = c(Treatment, Site))

get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Error in solve.default(crossprod(model.matrix(mod))) :    system is
> computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 7.14179e-18

The variables `plant.id` `treatment` and `site` are all factors. I have tried the variable type `year` as numeric and as a factor. The variable `Pb` is numeric.

There are a total of 38 observations in this dataset.

Comment: Usually this is caused when 2 or more variables which are highly correlated with one another. I would reccomend looking at the correlation of all pairs of your variables to see if any are highly correlated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928796/system-is-computationally-singular-reciprocal-condition-number-in-r)