How to solve "system is computationally singular"?
I have been busy in R this past weekend testing my data. However, I continually ran into an error message. It says;
Error in solve.default(vcov(x)[names.coefs_wo_int, names.coefs_wo_int], : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.44339e-18

I tested for multicollinarity but that was not the case. However, since all my data is monthly except emissions, I did annual emissions by month. For example: the annual emissions is 20,000. Then in January the emissions are 20,000, in February 20,000 etc. I think this is the reason for the error I'm getting. If I am going to make all my other data annual I hardly keep any observations. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I make use of a pooled OLS model to test the impact of scope 1 and scope 2 on the return. I also make use of control variables, which are all monthly measured.
I'm not very familiar with r so I don't really know how to solve this problem.

This issue has been answered very well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928796/system-is-computationally-singular-reciprocal-condition-number-in-r It is hard to tell where your specific problem is without looking at the code but the above link should help get you started.
